# Parse: Error: classname '_Session' must start with a letter

Tags: ios, parse-platform, xcode6.1

when I drop class or add a column in my parse.. I stuck in error " Error: classname '_Session' must start with a letter" please help

Comment: Could you please include the code that you're using?

Comment: add a snapshot of your data model in parse . Check if class name is _Session or Session

Comment: It seems like a general problem - check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28425820/trouble-dropping-a-class-column-from-parse

Comment: The problem is with Parse. You can review the status of this bug here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1539329073009016/