# Trouble Dropping a class/column from Parse

Tags: android, ios, parse-platform

I am trying to drop a few columns that i don't need from parse. I keep getting the following error.

Error: classname '_Session' must start with a letter parse

Not sure why this is happening - or if this is a bug.

I also get this error when I drop a Class.

Is there a way around this?

UPDATE:

I just tried and i was able to add and remove columns in the db.

I hope the fix is permanent :)

Comment: I've got exactly the same problem when I try to create a relation with the _User table on the interface.

Comment: It looks like a major bug on the parse.com interface which occured recently.

Nothing works anymore: delete class, add column, drop column...

I hope they will push a fix soon...

Comment: Are you doing that by code or by UI in parse.com?

Comment: @IAmDav for some reason im able add new records to the db, but just not able to drop columns via the browser interface.

Comment: @Ronaldoh1 , Just tried that in my test project, it works as expected. I have done: More->Delete Column->
then selected column that I want remove, And -> Drop Column

Comment: It seems like a bug on Parse' s side (due to an update?) as I cannot do stuff (eg add columns) that I did a few hours ago. Hope they sort it out soon.

Comment: I've also noticed this. I can't add or drop any columns.  I've submitted a bug report to Parse!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was going to post this as a comment but I don't have enough reputation.

This is indeed a bug in parse that is being addressed. The bug thread for it can be found here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1539329073009016/

Comment: They've fixed the issue. I just re-tried. and the Class drop works now.

Answer (score 0):

This bug has been fixed. You can now add or remove columns.